# Show alert on browser close but don't show alert while closing from logoff

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my application when user logs out the browser is closed. And on browser close I am throwing an alert. Now what I want is if I directly close the browser window alert should come but if window is closed through logout alert should not come as I have shown another confirm message of logout.

```
function closeEditorWarning(){
    for (var i=0;i<childWindow.length;i++) {
        if (childWindow[i] && !childWindow[i].closed) childWindow[i].close();
        if(i==0) {
            alert("This will close all open e-App applications");
        }
    }
    window.close();  
}
window.onbeforeunload = closeEditorWarning;
```

And this is my logout code

```
    $('#'+id).click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#centerContent').load('<%=request.getContextPath()%>/'+target);
    });
} else {
    $('#'+id).click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var r=confirm("logout");
        if (r==true)
        {
            flag=true;
            for (var i=0;i<childWindow.length;i++) {
                if (childWindow[i] && !childWindow[i].closed) childWindow[i].close();
            }
            window.close();
        } else { }
    });
}
```

Comment: are there any errors logged in firebug

Comment: Ugly hack, assign `window.onbeforeunload` to `null` when the user confirms log off.

Comment: Set a beforeunload listener. If the user logs off, remove the listener as part of the log off process. Otherwise, it is called when the beforeunload event occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Use a flag. Set the flag when log OFF is clicked.

Check the flag before showing the alert

Answer (score 0):

set a hidden field with user logon status and on close check:

```
if($('#isUserLogIn').text()=='true')
{
  //show alert
}
```